# twitter like pagination in django using jquery

Tags: jquery, django, twitter, pagination

Can someone suggest example of twitter like pagination where someone clicks on the more button and it loads the results in the next page in `django` using `jquery`

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/django-endless-pagination/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [django-endless-pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is what you are looking for.